# Non Browser Client talking to Application Load Balancer + Cognito - What is the correct way to authenticate user requests?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-application-load-balancer

I want to have a Non Browser Client talk to an Application Load Balancer and send authenticated requests on behalf of a user in a Cognito pool. While my proof of concept is currently working, the Non Browser Client (a C# program) is manually constructing HTTP requests as though it is a browser and it just doesn't seem to be the right way of doing it.

Is there some way to do this via the SDK or some proper API I can consume?

I have included diagrams and my proof of concept code to illustrate my scenario.
If this is in fact the correct way of going about it, I'll just refactor and move forward.

[High Level

[image: High Level]

Sequence Diagram

[image: Sequence Diagram]

```
/// <summary>
/// Proof of Concept Code. 
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public static async Task ManualAuthAppLb2()
{
    using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler 
    { 
        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator, 
        AllowAutoRedirect = false 
    })

    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        //--------------------------------------------------------//
        //Go to /secure_page and get redirected //
        var url = new Uri("https://<app_lb_id>.elb.amazonaws.com/secure_page");
        var req = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            RequestUri = url
        };
        var response = await client.SendAsync(req);
        //--------------------------------------------------------//


        //--------------------------------------------------------//
        //Follow First Redirect to cognito /authorize page
        var headers = response.Headers;
        var rediruri = headers.First(h => h.Key.ToLower() == "location").Value.First();

        req = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            RequestUri = new Uri(rediruri)
        };

        response = await client.SendAsync(req);
        //--------------------------------------------------------//


        //--------------------------------------------------------//
        //Follow next redirect to cognito /login page
        headers = response.Headers;

        var cookies = headers.First(h => h.Key.ToLower() == "set-cookie").Value.ToList();
        var csrfToken = cookies.First().Split('=')[1]
                .Split(';')[0]; ;

        rediruri = headers.First(h => h.Key.ToLower() == "location").Value.First();

        req = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            RequestUri = new Uri(rediruri)
        };

        response = await client.SendAsync(req);
        //--------------------------------------------------------//


        //--------------------------------------------------------//
        //Post Login Data to cognito
        headers = response.Headers;
        var data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            ["_csrf"] = csrfToken,
            ["username"] = "someuser",
            ["password"] = "somepassword"

        };

        req = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            RequestUri = new Uri(rediruri),
            Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data)
        };

        response = await client.SendAsync(req);
        //--------------------------------------------------------//



        //--------------------------------------------------------//
        //Follow Redirect Back to Application Load Balancer
        headers = response.Headers;
        rediruri = headers.First(h => h.Key.ToLower() == "location").Value.First();

        req = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            RequestUri = new Uri(rediruri)
        };

        response = await client.SendAsync(req);
        headers = response.Headers;
        rediruri = headers.First(h => h.Key.ToLower() == "location").Value.First();
        //--------------------------------------------------------//



        //--------------------------------------------------------//
        //Follow redirect back to /secure_page
        req = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            RequestUri = new Uri(rediruri)
        };

        response = await client.SendAsync(req);
        headers = response.Headers;


        Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        //--------------------------------------------------------//
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an amazon SDK for C# : the image shows the packages used to develop such application.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I have the SDKs and I've done some googling but I can't see how I can apply them to my particular use case.  For example, I've looked at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/cognito-authentication-extension.html and obtained an access token for a user using the SDK, but then I don't know how or whether that access token can be used to authenticate requests against the App Load Balancer.

Comment: Do your authentication process work providing access and refresh tokens ?

Comment: If you're referring to my original post, yes that process worked but it doesn't involve access or refresh tokens. 

As for https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/cognito-authentication-extension.html, yes that first example worked for me and I got an access token but then I'm not sure how to use that token for requests I send to the Application Load Balancer.

Comment: Additional initialisation for Http requests :           request.Headers.Add("Authorization", CurrentIdToken);
      request.Headers.Add("x-api-key"    , APIKey);